# Large number of HTML5 attribute questions?

Tags: discussion, support, clean-up

I've noticed a recent uptick in the number of [HTML5 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html5) about HTML5 attributes:

**15th November**

- [What values can the HTML5 aria-label attribute have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183450/what-values-can-the-html5-aria-label-attribute-have)

**14th November**

- [What is html5 aria attribute used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4180738/what-is-html5-aria-attribute-used-for) (**deleted**)
- [What is the definition of the HTML5 aria-* attribute in laymans terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4179987/what-is-the-definition-of-the-html5-aria-attribute-in-laymans-terms)
- [Can someone explain the HTML5 aria-* attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176844/can-someone-explain-the-html5-aria-attribute)

**13th November**

- [What values can the HTML5/XHTML role attribute have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170356/what-values-can-the-html5-xhtml-role-attribute-have)

**12th November**

- [HTML5 spellcheck attribute question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4162124/html5-spellcheck-attribute-question)
- [Can someone give me more info on what the The role and aria-* HTML5 attributes do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169671/can-someone-give-me-more-info-on-what-the-the-role-and-aria-html5-attributes-do)

**11th November**

- [HTML5 can I use a relative URL for the itemtype attributes value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4160382/html5-can-i-use-a-relative-url-for-the-itemtype-attributes-value) **(deleted)**
- [HTML5 what is the itemscope attribute and what does it do in laymans terms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158876/html5-what-is-the-itemscope-attribute-and-what-does-it-do-in-laymans-terms)

**10th November**

- [What kind of values can the HTML5 itemid attribute have?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148119/what-kind-of-values-can-the-html5-itemid-attribute-have)
- [What is the HTML5 itemid attribute and how do you use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4147599/what-is-the-html5-itemid-attribute-and-how-do-you-use-it)

**9th November**

- [What does it mean in HTML 5 when an attribute is a boolean attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4139786/what-does-it-mean-in-html-5-when-an-attribute-is-a-boolean-attribute)
- [HTML 5 draggable attribute question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131377/html-5-draggable-attribute-question)

**8th November**

- [Which browsers currently support the HTML5 contextmenu attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121461/which-browsers-currently-support-the-html5-contextmenu-attribute)
- [HTML5 contextmenu attribute question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121351/html5-contextmenu-attribute-question)
- [Any of the browsers does support HTML5's context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120588/any-of-the-browsers-does-support-html5s-context-menu)

**7th November**

- [Can someone explain what the contextmenu attribute in HTML5 does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4119106/can-someone-explain-what-the-contextmenu-attribute-in-html5-does)
- [HTML5 contenteditable attribute question. [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116963/html5-contenteditable-attribute-question-closed)
- [HTML5 contenteditable question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116833/html5-contenteditable-question)

---

These question seem suspect because they seem to follow a pattern:

1. Asked by new, unregistered users
2. Very short questions, usually only one or two lines with no elaboration
3. Fairly simple questions that can be answered by looking at the specifications
4. A lot of them are duplicates of previous questions

Now them problem is that these are not invalid questions. It's just that this number of extremely basic questions, many of them duplicates, been asked within a relatively short period of time seems very suspicious, or at least it does so to me. I'm going to *guess* (though there's really no point in doing so, since I have no hard evidence proving this) that these questions are coming from students in the same school on the same course, and that these are all homework questions. But that's **only** a guess.

Now I'm not saying that we should suspend these users or anything, but at least we should clean it up by closing some of these as dupes.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm going to guess (though there's
>   really no point in doing so, since I
>   have no hard evidence proving this)
>   that these questions are coming from
>   students in the same school on the
>   same course, and that these are all
>   homework questions.

So? While duplicate questions should obviously be avoided asking homework questions is allowed on stack overflow.

Remember that the OP is not under any obligation to disclose whether the question is homework or not. If you believe it is - and you are personally against homework questions - then you certainly have the right to not answer them.

I'm certainly not against closing the dups but I don't understand what the homework part has to do with it.

Comment: If I haven't made it clear, it's not just that these are `[homework]` questions, but that these are also **bad** questions. The HTML5 spec is fairly short compared to most other language specs and is online for everybody to read, and some of the questions are almost silly when you look at them, yet the same ridiculously simple question get's asked again and again and again, even when the asker has been pointed to the language specs.

Comment: The proper thing to do is downvote them then